# Binding to static list of static class

Tags: c#, wpf, list, binding

I have static class with current transaction information like this:

```
public static class BKM 
{
   public static List<Ticket> Tickets {get;set;}
}
```

What I want to bind to Tickets.Count property in XAML.

When I type something like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static p:BKM.Tickets.Count}}" />
```

where p is

```
xmlns:p="clr-namespace:TicketApplication"
```

I get errors

> Error  22  Nested types are not supported: BKM.Tickets.
>   Error   21  Cannot find the type 'BKM.Tickets'. Note that type names are case sensitive.
>   Error   23  Cannot find the member "Count" on the target type.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect one problem is that you want the *source* to be `BKM.Tickets`, but you want the *path* to be `Count`. So try this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static p:BKM.Tickets} Path=Count}" />
```

And as Sriram says, you should make `Tickets` a property as well, e.g.

```
public static List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
```

You should also consider moving away from global state, which is hard to test and reason about.

Answer (score 1):

`Tickets` should be a property. DataBinding to field is not supported.

```
public static class BKM 
{
   public static List<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
}
```

If Property isn't a problem then I think Jon got it right. You need to bind to `BKM.Tickets` property and bind to `Count` as mentioned in Jon's answer.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static p:BKM.Tickets} Path=Count}" />
```

Comment: I forgot to add that it is property ;)

Comment: @Lukas Then jon's answer should help you.

Answer (score 0):

put this property

```
public static int MyCounts
{
    get { return Tickets == null ? 0: Tickets.Count; }
}
```

and Bind to it

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static p:BKM.MyCounts}}" />
```